# UIView.animateWithDuration change in Xcode 6 Beta 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to animate a change in dimension for a UITableView. The following code worked in beta 4:

```
     UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {
                tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, 0 - self.calcTopOffsetToCell(indexPath), tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height + 190)
            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                self.selectedIndex = indexPath
                cell.amountTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
            })
```

In beta 5, I get the error "Missing argument for parameter 'delay' in call"

If I change the function to specify the delay:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: Double(0), options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
            tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, 0 - self.calcTopOffsetToCell(indexPath), tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height + 190)
            }, completion: {
                (finished: Bool) in
                self.selectedIndex = indexPath
                cell.amountTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
        });
```

I get the error "Extra argument 'delay' in call"

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or this is a bug. Any ideas?

Even if I used the most basic syntax:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, 0 - self.calcTopOffsetToCell(indexPath), tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height + 190)

        })
```

I get the "Missing argument for parameter 'delay' in call" error

Comment: I've had the same error but in a different situation. Turns out it was  because in my animation block a method was expecting a CGFloat and I was using a double. Is your calcTopOffsetToCell function return a CGFloat? My guess is if you comment out the `tableView.frame` line the error will go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the error was actually to do with calcTopOffsetToCell() not returning a CGFloat and the IDE error was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, this saved my time. At current stage (xcode6 beta5), "Missing argument for parameter" error pretty much means there's some problem inside the block.